# Mock a command failing

Tags: unit-testing, powershell, pester

```
Set-Location "C:\thisDirDoesNotExist"
If(-not $?)
{
    Write-Error -Message "error"
    Exit 1
}
```

How do I mock a command failing? In the above code, the Set-Location command will error with a non-terminating error. The $? variable will be set to false and an error message will be outputted and the script will exit.

How do I mock the Set-Location command to set the $? variable to false?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `-ErrorVariable` parameter. In the following example, the variable `$locationError` will be set when `Set-Location` cmdlet fails:

```
Set-Location "C:\" -ErrorVariable locationError
If($locationError)
{
    Write-Error -Message "error"
    Exit 1
}
```

Now all you have to do is to set `$locationError`to `$true` to mock your failure.

Comment: I've tried "Mock Set-Location { $locationError = $true }" but when I get to the if statement that checks $locationError , the $locationError variable is empty.

Comment: Ah, I missed that part that you are working with pester. However, if you throw an exception within your Set-Location mock it should work.

Comment: I got there in the end, you pointed me in the right direction with this. So I used the code you provided, but in the mock I used the following: "Set-Location { Write-Error "Error" }". This will populate the $locationError variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Throw` to force whatever error you want. $? will be False after the `Throw`.

Comment: If I use throw inside the mock for Set-Location the test fails saying that there an error occurred in Context block.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, a mock to produce an error, with a test to verify you got the error looks like this:

### Test code

```
Describe 'mock an error' {
    Context 'terminating error' {
        Mock -CommandName Set-Location -MockWith {Write-Error 'My Error' -ErrorAction 'Stop'} 

        it 'should throw' {
            {Set-Location -Path .\foo -ErrorAction Stop} | should throw 'My Error'
        }
    }

    Context 'non-terminating error' {
        Mock -CommandName Set-Location -MockWith {Write-Error 'My Error' } 

        it 'should throw' {
            {Set-Location -Path .\foo -ErrorVariable slError
            $Global:slError=$slError} | should not throw
            $global:slError.count |should be 1
            $Global:slError[0].Exception.Message | should be 'My Error'
        }
    }
}
```

### Results

> ```
> Describing mock an error
>    Context terminating error
>     [+] should throw 551ms
>    Context non-terminating error
> Write-Error 'My Error'  : My Error
> At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Pester\3.4.0\Functions\Mock.ps1:1056 char:9
> +         & $___ScriptBlock___ @___BoundParameters___ @___ArgumentList_ ...
> +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException
>
>     [+] should throw 164ms
> ```